# Transfer a project to git?

Tags: git, project, transfer

I have a project on a local machine, and a git repository on a remote server. Is there a way I can push/commit/transfer this project to the remote server? It's telling me "not a git repository", I know that! I just want it on the remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `clone` the remote repo onto your local machine, copy your files into the directory,  `add` the new files, `commit` them and `push` them back to the remote server.

```
cd /to/some/directory
git clone [uri]
```

Then copy your files into the directory

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Added local project files"
git push origin master
```

Assuming you know git, you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: Did a slight variation of the above. If you're coming from SVN, git makes no sense, none, zero.

Comment: It definitely takes a bit of getting used to I'll give you that. Once you understand it though, you come to love it. Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the project a git repo yet?  If not, you'll need to first initialize it as a git repository on the local machine, make sure that all the project files are committed, and then push the project files to the remote repo.

Comment: So `git init`, then `git add .`, then `git commit -m "Please don't delete my stuff!"`, then `git push user@repository`? This is guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your remote repository must be a bare repository. Otherwise you can't push to this remote repository. To create it, just pass the option bare: `git init --bare`.